# Pourquoi il faut le subjonctif après « avoir l’habitude que »?

Tags: subjonctif

Ça fait quelques mois que je suis tombé sur [ce site](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/fr-avoir-lhabitude-que-mode.3268637/) (en résumé, c'est la même question mais la réponse n'apporte aucune explication) juste en cherchant "avoir l'habitude que subjonctif" et je n'arrive toujours pas à trouver une explication. Ça semble être le seul site web que j'aie trouvé sur ce sujet mais cette tournure et son utilisation semblent être bien répandues. Alors, quelle est l'explication ?

Answer (score 5):

*Avoir l'habitude que...* introduit une appréciation. Le subjonctif est utilisé dans ce cas.

> Il a l'habitude que je **réponde** à ses questions.

Pareil avec:

> *Il aime que...*, *il apprécie que...*, *il regrette que...*

Le subjonctif est aussi utilisé quand il s'agit d'un souhait ou d'une hypothèse :

> *Il souhaite que...*, *il veut/voudrait que...*, *il envisage que...*

En revanche, avec une affirmation ou quelque chose qui est considéré comme vrai, ce sera l'indicatif :

> Il sait que je **réponds** à ses questions.

> *Il pense que...*, *il dit que...*, *il constate que...*, *il suppose que...*, *il affirme que...*

Comment: Bien sûr, "Il a l'habitude que je réponde à ses questions" est un énoncé d'un fait, une affirmation, ni une appréciation ni un souhait ni une hypothèse. Je ne comprends pas.

Comment: @HarryAudus Cette phrase sous entend que ce n'est pas nécessairement le cas. Il s'agit donc d'une appréciation : que la réponse soit obtenue n'est pas considéré comme un fait sûr.

Comment: @jilliagre: Merci.  C'est à tort que j'ai compris que le mot « appréciation » dans ce contexte est synonyme de « appreciation » (ou « recognition ») en anglais, au lieu de « assessment ». Alors, cela a plus de sens pour moi.